# Gulp unexpected token in linux not windows

Tags: docker, gulp

I have this strange behaviour. I installed gulp on my windows machine which works fine. I then installed a Ubuntu image in a docker, loaded the folder as a volume and installed gulp (same version). But when I run it I get the following error.

```
gulp.task('clean', () => del(dist.base));
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Gulp version

```
[00:21:34] CLI version 3.9.1
[00:21:34] Local version 3.9.1
```

Comment: What version of node are you running it on in the docker instance? And, does that version support function arrow syntax?

Comment: It might be a file encoding issue. Do you still see the issue if you run your file through dos2unix or a similar tool?